# Detect opening of PluginSidebar in Wordpress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm looking to reinitialise some settings and state data when my PluginSidebar is reopened, but I'm struggling to find anything useful in wp.data core/editor or similar that I could use to best create a subscription.

Does gutenberg provide any such data where I can check to see if the side panel is open or shut, so that I could fire a function of my choice every time it opens?

At present, I have a mutationObserver in place listening to see if it opens, which is quite clunky.

Some pseudo-code of my preferred approach.

```
subscribe(() => {
    if (select('core/editor').isPluginSidebarOpen()) {
        open = true
    } else {
        open = false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is so very close.. the function exists and is called [isPluginSidebarOpened](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-edit-post/#ispluginsidebaropened) and comes from `core/edit-post`, eg:

```js
import { subscribe, select } from '@wordpress/data';

subscribe(() => {
    if (select('core/edit-post').isPluginSidebarOpened()) {
        // Is open..
    } else {
        // Is closed..
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe my pseudocode was so close!